# How to check if dictionary value is string or an array

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I have data from server like

```
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "16",
     "children": "",
     "products": [
                   {...},
                   {...}
                 ]
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "17",
     "children": "",
     "products": [
                   {...},
                   {...}
                 ]
   }
]
```

so I save it like  `[[String: Any]]`, and `Any` is because there can be `Int`, `String` or `Dict` at the values.

The point is that "children" key can be `NSConstantstring` and can be casted to `String`, and also it can be `NSArray` and can be casted to `[[String: Any]]` too. So I need to find a way to detect type of that value. But all I tried caused error.

How can i fix this?

UPD
not much code)

inside alamofire response:

```
        let data = responseJSON.result.value! as! [String: Any]
        let subCategory = data["children"] as! [[String: Any]]
        //check 

        for item in subCategory {
            print(type(of: item["children"]!))//__NSArrayI or __NSCFConstantString

        }
```

if I try something like `print(type(of: item["children"] as! String))` it prints `String` if there is `__NSCFConstantString`, but if not - it crashes with error `Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10934fe48) to 'NSString' (0x1083e8568)`

UPD 2
there is no problem with data, all parsed and save correctly and printing out correctly too

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @Kamran have updated the question, thank you

Comment: Are you trying to decode a JSON?

Comment: @BencePattogato there is no problem with data, all parsed and saved correctly and printing out correctly too

Comment: use `SwiftyJSON` it has overriden properties like int, float which returns a optional value, if value is nil then it means value is either not of  the type you are expecting it to or value does not exist

Comment: @nastassia The answer by `llya` should fix the issue you have.

Comment: or use https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just cast value from dictionary to needed type:

```
if let string = dictionary["children"] as? String {
    // Do something with string
} else if array = dictionary["children"] as? [Any] {
    // Do something with array
}
```